# Get HTML Element Based on Style in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, css, html-agility-pack

I have HTML in a string and need to use C# to extract a particular node based on its CSS style.  In the past, I've parsed HTML using HtmlAgilityPack.  This parses the HTML very well, and gives me all the elements in an organized fashion.  And I can even filter or query by attributes.  The problem is that it doesn't "understand" how the CSS hierarchy works.  CSS can be inline, at the beginning of the file, or in a parent node.  The browser is intelligent enough to know what the final rendering of an element should be.  HtmlAgilityPack can give me the attributes of a particular element, but I don't see a way for it to tell me what the ultimate style of the element would be.  For example, an element might not have *any* attributes, but yet have a particular style based on the more complex CSS logic (style from a parent node, etc.)

How can I query the in-memory HTML, without using a headless browser, to find elements whose final rendering (were they to be rendered in a browser) would have a particular style?  (Similar to how jQuery does it, eg: $('[color="#0000ff"]')

I don't want a lot of complicated regexs or similiar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) use for the butterfly layout web application it's a one client site. A web page multiple CSS examples External, Internal, Inline use as user needed. Every CSS works the same goals but it maintains order. the higher order is the **Inline CSS** then **Internal CSS** and then **external CSS** we get it external file. Every CSS selector is not the same example id, class, adjoin, parent, sibling and others selectors. read this article https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/.

jQuery selector and CSS Selector are the same but jquery is work different way every jQuery CSS contain in **Inline CSS**. from your ask `$('[color="#0000ff"]')` is an a attribute selector. this html example are `<div color="#0000ff">content</div>` but it's not seticesfy W3C. it's also an custom attribute of an html element the W3C are recomended for custom attribute prefix `data-` example `<div data-color="#0000ff">content</div>` you got it http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/.

**--Thanks --**

Comment: Thanks.  But how does this answer the question?